# Predict for arima

Tags: r

After I use arima predict, I got the result of out of sample. And then I calculated by hand like `coefficient(fit)%*% c(1,y(future value))` for forecasting.

### However those two are different!! I think those values should be same.What happen to them? I missed something about that?

This is simple example.

```
set.seed(1)
zts <- ts(rnorm(240), start=c(1990,1), frequency=12)
fit <- arima(window(zts, end=c(2000,12),frequency=12), order=c(1,0,0))
Call:
arima(x = window(zts, end = c(2000, 12), frequency = 12), order = c(1, 0, 0))

Coefficients:
         ar1  intercept
       -0.0153     0.0954
 s.e.   0.0872     0.0732

sigma^2 estimated as 0.7294:  log likelihood = -166.47,  aic = 338.94

predict(fit, n.ahead=1)
$pred
       Jan
2001 0.1059105

 $se
       Jan
2001 0.8540253
```

#### I used the second method!

```
t (c(0.0954, -0.0153 ))%*%c(1, 0.531496193)
: 0.08726811
```

===========>  0.08726811 is different 0.1059105.

Comment: 0.08726811 is similar to  s.e.   0.0872(your arima coefficients)

Comment: what is the second value in the second parentheses of the last piece of code `0.531496193`? It actually should be the last value of your data...

Comment: 0.531496193 is 2001. Jan in zts (original data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In R `arima` first demeans your data before fitting a model. I can reproduce the `predict` result:

```
coef(fit)%*%c(window(zts, end=c(2000,12),frequency=12)[132]-coef(fit)[2],1)
0.1059105
```

Comment: window(zts, end=c(2000,12),frequency=12)[132] ---> get -0.5888945 this one is for 2000,12: This is different the value: zts 2001 Jan = 0.531496193.  Usually if you want to forecast y[100], then coef(fit)%*%c(, y[100]) not y[99]?

Comment: If you are generating one-step-ahead prediction you should use the last value in your time series data, in your case it is December 2000, and not January 2001, this is what you are attempting to predict

Comment: Yes.Thanks. I am confused the rhs variable.

Comment: Then it would be nice if you accepted my answer :-)